# Unable to attach third-party library to theme

Tags: 8

I have a multi value media field on a content type and I want to display it as a slider on the node if more than one image is uploaded to that media field.I am using slick library for this purpose.
Defined the library in the libraries.yml file and then i changed the twig output of the filed template to get the desired html out as mentioned on the slick website - http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

theme name : bs

bs.libraries.yml

```
slick:
  version: VERSION
  css:
      css/slick.css: {}
      css/slick-theme.css: {}
  js:
    js/slick.min.js: {}
    js/slick.config.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/drupal
    - core/jquery
```

slick.config.js

```
(function ($, Drupal, window, document) {

Drupal.behaviors.bsSlickConfig = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {

    $('.responsive').slick({
      dots: true,
      infinite: false,
      speed: 300,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 4,
      responsive: [
        {
          breakpoint: 1024,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 3,
            infinite: true,
            dots: true
          }
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 600,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 2,
            slidesToScroll: 2
          }
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 480,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1
          }
        }
        // You can unslick at a given breakpoint now by adding:
        // settings: "unslick"
        // instead of a settings object
      ]
    });

  }
};

  } (jQuery, Drupal, this, this.document));
```

field--node--field-slideshow.html.twig

```
{{ attach_library('bs/slick') }}
{%
  set classes = [
    'slideshow__slides',
    'responsive',
    'field',
    'field--name-' ~ field_name|clean_class,
    'field--type-' ~ field_type|clean_class,
    'field--label-' ~ label_display,

  ]
%}
{%
  set title_classes = [
    'field__label',
    label_display == 'visually_hidden' ? 'visually-hidden',
  ]
%}
<div{{ attributes.addClass(classes, 'field__items') }}>
  {% for item in items %}
    <div{{ item.attributes.addClass('field__item') }}>{{ item.content 
}}</div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

the slider is loading but not working on the individual media but on the entire field as a whole.So all the three images in this case seem to slide at the same time.
[image: here is what it looks like]

Comment: The code and the rendered HTML markup look correct, it is more likely you are having CSS collisions.

Comment: **BRAVO :)** , it was css indeed , now i added the css files correcly and it worked , thank u @Hudri

Comment: There is one **issue** though, on the last slide i see all the images one below the other :(.I see one slide as desired and previous next animations work, as soon as i click on the last slide, they all stack like cards as show in the image in the question :(